# How to plot panel data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel

I have the following csv file:

```
  id year  item valuesound growtharea
1 16 2005 Wheat   9784.490         NA
2 16 2006 Wheat  10020.720  0.0241437
3 16 2007 Wheat   9232.796 -0.0786298
4 16 2008 Wheat   8567.893 -0.0720154
5 16 2009 Wheat  10292.670  0.2013073
6 16 2010 Wheat   9274.589 -0.0989134
```

After the plm, the panel looks like this:

```
> library(plm)
> panel <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("id", "year"), drop.index = TRUE)
> head(panel)
         item valuesound growtharea
16-2005 Wheat   9784.490         NA
16-2006 Wheat  10020.720  0.0241437
16-2007 Wheat   9232.796 -0.0786298
16-2008 Wheat   8567.893 -0.0720154
16-2009 Wheat  10292.670  0.2013073
16-2010 Wheat   9274.589 -0.0989134
```

I have problems in graphing this panel. I would like to create a line graph with ggplot2, so it would show a line of each "id" across the "year" the values of "valuesound".

I've tried with ggplot2

```
ggplot(panel, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, group = id)) +
   geom_line()
```

But always I have errors such as "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'year' not found".
I don't know where the mistake is. I've changed drop.index=FALSE, but still I cannot create a nice graph with colors for each line.
Could you please help me to create a graph using this panel data?

Comment: Your original dataset is already in the format you need it for the plot. Run the `ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, group = id)) +
   geom_line()` where `df` is your original csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original dataset has the separate `id` and `year` variables that you need to plot changes to `valuesound` over time. There is no need to change to `pdata.frame` as doing so indexes the id and year variables.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)

# where object df is your original dataset
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = year, y = valuesound)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = as.factor(id)))
```

[image]