# Plot large panel data in R by category

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, panel

I have a dataset (`df`) that looks like this:

```
   EIN Year  Cat Fund 
1  16 2005   A   9784.490       
2  16 2006   A  10020.720  
3  16 2007   A   9232.796 
4  15 2008   B   8567.893 
5  15 2009   B  10292.670  
6  17 2010   C   9274.589
```

The data has relatively large dimensions (around 300k observations), which makes plotting a potentially slow process. I would like to plot the variable `Fund` for each year, by the identifier `EIN`. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248543/how-to-plot-panel-data-in-r) I have tried the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Fund)) +
geom_line(aes(linetype = as.factor(EIN)))
```

Here are my questions:

1. This code becomes pretty slow given the high amount of observations that I have. Do you suggest any alternatives that could speed up the process?
2. Since I have a huge number of EINs, the legend ends-up taking all the space available for the graph, so I would like to get rid of it unsuccesfully. I tried adding `+ guides(fill=FALSE)` at the end, but it did not work. Any advice?
3. If I wanted to either subset or color code my plot by Cat, what would be the best way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please, one question per submisison. This one has three.

Comment: Also if you have a huge number of unique EINs, how do you plan to generate an equally huge amount of different linetypes that can be discriminated by the casual observer?

Comment: Thanks, @teunbrand. Indeed, I do not need to have different line-types for all EINs, it would suffice to have a different one per category.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the legend using:

```
+ theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

To subset (facet) your plot, especially if there aren't too many categories, use facet_wrap:

```
+ facet_wrap(~Cat)
```

To colour instead, put `colour = Cat` inside your `aes()` calll.